# how to ignore child fields while fire click event on full document

Tags: jquery, html, css

This Is my code for toggle div , i want that my div named #credits should toggle when click on other part of document , this code running perfectly but there is a problem that when i click on the form of this div, that time it also toggles . Please help me to prevent it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_stu').click(function() {
    $('#credits').slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().is('#add_stu')) {
      $("#credits").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#credits {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right " id="add_stu" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Add Student</b>
</button>
<div id="credits" class="bg-white padded poop text-center">
  <!-- The user image in the menu -->
  <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">
      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">

      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected value="val0">Add Student to a room</option>
        <option value="val1">Room A</option>
        <option value="val2">Room B</option>
        <option value="val3">Room C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="width:100%;">Create Student</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to click button then toggle effect are there  ?? right

Comment: no , i just want that , when i click on input fields it should not toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following conditions:

Check if the clicked element is not child of the button or of the credits element using `closest()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add_stu').click(function() {
    $('#credits').slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!($(e.target).closest('#add_stu').length || $(e.target).closest('#credits').length)) {

      $("#credits").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#credits {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right " id="add_stu" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Add Student</b>
</button>
<div id="credits" class="bg-white padded poop text-center">
  <!-- The user image in the menu -->
  <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">

      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">

      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected value="val0">Add Student to a room</option>
        <option value="val1">Room A</option>
        <option value="val2">Room B</option>
        <option value="val3">Room C</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="width:100%;">Create Student</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this edited some Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var count = 1;
  $('#add_stu').click(function() {
   count++
    if(count >1){
    $('#credits').slideToggle("slow");
    count--;
    }
    else{
       $("#credits").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
  });
```

```css
#credits {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right " id="add_stu" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Add Student</b>
</button>
<div id="credits" class="bg-white padded poop text-center">
  <!-- The user image in the menu -->
  <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">
      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">

      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected value="val0">Add Student to a room</option>
        <option value="val1">Room A</option>
        <option value="val2">Room B</option>
        <option value="val3">Room C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="width:100%;">Create Student</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside the `#add_stu` click event - add `stopPropagation` (to make sure the click doesn't bubble up the DOM tree to the `document`.
2. Inside the `document` click event - check if the current target have the any  parent `#credits`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_stu').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#credits').slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).parents('#credits').length > 0) {
      $("#credits").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#credits {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right " id="add_stu" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Add Student</b>
</button>
<div id="credits" class="bg-white padded poop text-center">
  <!-- The user image in the menu -->
  <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">
      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper text-center">

      <div>
        <input class="form-control " placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field_wrapper">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected value="val0">Add Student to a room</option>
        <option value="val1">Room A</option>
        <option value="val2">Room B</option>
        <option value="val3">Room C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="width:100%;">Create Student</button>
  </form>
</div>
```